# Facing mostly-faced decks

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question

In my day job, I am often called upon to take a large stack of—let's call them cards—and make sure that a large majority of them are facing in a particular direction. In most cases, there are long "runs" of cards facing one way or the other.

Assume two permanent marks stand at either end of the deck.

I can make a few types of "moves":

1. Look at a card.
2. Mark a place in the deck.
3. Pull a stack of cards between two marks out and flip it end over end.
4. Pull a stack of cards between two marks out and move it to one end or another of the deck, possibly flipping it in the process.

Restrictions:
 1. I can have a maximum of about three marks in the deck at a time, aside from the end marks, because I only have so many fingers and so much short term memory.
 2. An unmarked spot can be aimed for, but not necessarily hit with any precision. That is, if I want to check a card half-way into the deck, that will be $\tfrac 1 2 \pm \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$.
 3. No stack over a certain size (say, $\tfrac 1 6$ of the deck, perhaps) can be moved/flipped at once. If this adds too much complexity, it can be relaxed.

The goal is to end up with a high probability of a large majority of the cards facing the right direction at a low expected cost, where each peek/mark move is fairly cheap and each flip/move move is fairly expensive. The technique must also be simple, as it is running on an FSM with limited available states (my working memory). Note that the deck may have up to approximately 2000 cards.